# jQuery - select elements that are not within a ID

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I select all elements that have a `title` attribute, but are not contained by a element with the `#boo` ID ?

like `$("*[title]").each()...`

but not elements which are in `#boo` :)

Comment: You'll get yelled at here if you use $('div#boo') or anything like that

Comment: because when you use a id selector (#) it's much faster because the browser itself just grabs the correct element and doesn't have to first sift through all the divs first. Although I'm quite sure that jQuery automatically turns it into just an Id selector

Comment: @quertymk: I didn't know that either. I usually try and be specific with IDs, div#boo instead of #boo, because you should know what they're being used on, they're not as open as classes... but I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("[title]").not("#boo [title]").each()
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/RaCLy/)

and as a side note, when you use `id` in getting the element, it is faster if you don't prefix the element's tag. For example, just use `#boo` instead of `div#boo`. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/RaCLy/1/) <-- try to look at the console of firebug for time comparison.

Comment: I humbly submit to your l33t3r code then. You are the greater ninja

Comment: I would +1 again if I could for the id only vs tag + id demo. nice job. Edit: Loophole, you have comments

Answer (score 6):

`$('*:not(#boo) *[title]');` should work.

Comment: Interesting approach :) I suspect it's not very efficient, but certainly a different way to think.

Comment: My brain thinks better in CSS selectors than in Javascript.... I prefer Reigel's answer, but I thought I'd throw my own in.

Comment: @Phrogz, actually I suspect it *may* be more efficient, if the structure of #boo is deep.

Comment: @Box9: My unbacked-by-code intuition tells me this is going to find _every_ element on the page (except #boo) and then call `getElementsByTagName('*')` on each. Perhaps Sizzle is smarter than that.

Comment: This seems to be valid for `querySelectorAll`. That's a big advantage.

Comment: Fastest solution: http://jsperf.com/element-not-within-another
But... It does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/93ckoeos/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('[title]').filter(function(){return $(this).parents('#boo').length === 0;})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter()`

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 2):

There are may ways to skin this cat. Here are two more:

```
$('[title]:not(#boo *[title])');
$('[title]').not('#boo *[title]');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this before and used something like:

```
$(":not(#boo) > [title]")
```